# Data Extraction from PDF and analyzing using NLP

Tags: python, pdf, nlp

I am trying to automate data extraction (e.g. number of plants, employees etc.) from annual reports of various companies and fill the data in relevant fields in excel sheet.

As of now I have thought of following process in Python:

1. Get PDF
2. Convert to text
3. Analyse data using NLP
4. Answer the pre-defined questions
5. Export relevant info (if found)

Problem is the data is very unstructured and Annual report format varies from company to company.
Can anyone kindly suggest a better way to automate this task?

Comment: You might find off-the-self tools for steps 1, 2, and 5, but 3 and 4 are very hard and require a lot of expertise and time. If you want to do them well.

Comment: Any Suggestion how can I get started with it? I have started learning NLP in python. I will really appreciate if you could guide me to some tutorial

Comment: NLP isn't something you easily learn in a tutorial. Typically it is taught in University courses or at higher-education institutes.